# Reading hardware-raided disks with software raid

Tags: raid, software-raid, hardware-raid

I have a computer with 2 disks on it in RAID 0. Unfortunately this PC just died yesterday and I need to get a VM out of the disk to transplant it in another computer, but I'm not sure if the raid controller will work with the different motherboard (additionally I don't have any PSU other than this that doesn't work with the appropriate 10 pin connector).

So the question is: if I put the 2 disks in another completely different motherboard, can I use software raid (from a live linux OS or somehing similar) to retrieve the data from the disk?

I want to be 100% sure that the software raid won't overwrite a single byte to the array, but rather preserve the existing configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can I use software raid to retrieve the data from the disk?

Almost certainly not no, hardware RAID and Software RAID systems are really very different, just restore from last backup.

Answer (score 0):

Linux RAID does recognize some so called hardware RAID formats. You may be lucky.

If you want to be absolutely sure that the original isn't modified, make an exact copy and work on that. You may need to buy big enough disks for that.

Additional advice:

- Don't use the motherboard RAID, use Linux RAID, it will work on any motherboard.
- Don't use RAID 0 for important things without a backup.